# Updating multiple values in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I update multiple values in MySQL?

This didn't work:

```
UPDATE test SET list=0,
price= 0.00 cprice= 0.00 WHERE test.id =3232
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to put a comma between the two different values,  for example:

```
UPDATE orders 
   SET listPrice = 0,
       bloggerPrice = 0.00,
       customerPrice = 0.00 
WHERE orders.id =245745
```

Answer (score 10):

You're missing a comma:

```
UPDATE orders SET 
    listPrice = 0, 
    bloggerPrice = 0.00, 
    customerPrice = 0.00 
WHERE 
    orders.id = 245745
```

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
UPDATE orders 
SET listprice=0, bloggerPrice=0.00, customerPrice=0.00 
WHERE id=245745
```